# Connecting different points (more than two) with different lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point

I have different points (stations) which I made as point layers in my map, and now I want to create a line network of a public transportation system, as such I want to connect different points (more then two, it might be even more than ten) to different lines.

I want the information of the line numbers which are crossing certain station in the proberties section of the certain stations.

On the other site, I want the information of the stations which are crossing by certain lines in the properties section of the lines.

What is the best tool for this?

EDIT: Yes, I know, I could easily make a line layer and just write the information manually in the chart , but that's not the way I want to do it respectively we are allowed too. Also, I have to use QGIS for that operation.

Answer (score 1):

For what I see, you will not be doing further network analysis, you only want the information of a layer on the other (points to lines and the other way around); so you are better off with a spatial join; if lines and points touch, you may use the tool ***Vector >> Data Management >> Join Attributes by location***. There you select point and line layers and the fields to add, you should check intersects and touches boxes.

If there's a distance from lines to points, you should make a buffer ***Vector >> geoprocessing >> buffer*** and then perform the join. Remember to check the CRS of both layers match and for the Buffer case these should be in a projected coordinate system (UTM or lambert)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first part of your question (line info to points, I think), but I have solved problems like your second (create line segments from points, where the line segments contain the point attribute info) with the QGIS tool **PointstoPaths** (note the plural Paths). This is an extraordinarily useful tool. Sadly, it is only available at QGIS v. 2.X. If you don't have v. 2.X installed, download the latest version at:

https://qgis.org/downloads/

For my Windows 10 machine, I use the install file *QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.28-2-Setup-x86_64.exe*.  This older version works just fine alongside other (later) QGIS versions.

Once installed, add the **PointstoPaths** plugin.

Run **PointstoPaths**, using your station points layer as the input. The **Point Group Field** will identify each unique transport "system" (such as an individual bus or rail line).

The **Point Order** field will identify the sequential order in which the bus, train, etc travels.

Important: You **must** check the *Line per Vertex* checkbox! It is this option that gives **PointstoPaths** its unique capability.

**PointstoPaths** will now output a line shapefile. Each segment in this shapefile will have two fields, *begin* and *end*. Not surprisingly, *begin* and *end* contain the beginning and ending sequential values that comprise each segment. These two fields are what make **PointstoPaths** so special, because each segment can now be related back to the two points that created it.  That is, you can now join the point layer to the new line layer to transfer any additional point attribute info to its respective line segment.